# Difference between SAVE, PROTECTED and PARAMETER for attributes module data entities

Tags: fortran

If I want to prevent module data from being changed during program execution, I seem to have at least three options in Fortran:

**1. using the `SAVE` statement**

```
module mymod

implicit none
save

integer :: i = 1

end mymod
```

**2. using the `PROTECTED` attribute**

```
module mymod

implicit none

integer, protected :: i = 1

end mymod
```

**3. using the `PARAMETER` attribute**

```
module mymod

implicit none

integer, parameter :: i = 1

end mymod
```

What are the differences and implications of the three options?

Comment: Those examples don't have at all the same purpose.  SAVE is implied for known compilers; any procedure which USEs the MODULE is permitted to modify. The variables effectively remain in scope (but inaccessible) when the MODULE is out of scope.  PROTECTED requires the compiler to allow modification only by procedures internal to that module, not exclusive of SAVE.  PARAMETER declares a constant, which may no longer exist after compilation, and of course the compiler should refuse to allow modification.  These should all be clear if you search web for adequate explanations.

Comment: Can you expand on your second sentence, please? Under what circumstances and when is SAVE implied and for which compilers? The rest of you comment should be an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer addresses the non-subtle aspects of the use of the entities named `i`.  There are a few other considerations to be made in more complicated cases.  It also uses the term *variable definition context*.  Loosely speaking, this means where a variable may appear such that its value *could* change.  This would be things like being the left-hand side of an assignment; appearing as a do variable or corresponding to an `intent(out)` argument.

1. `i` may appear in a variable definition context whenever it is accessible.
2. `i` (as a non-pointer object), where it is accessible, can appear in a variable definition context only in the scope of its module or descendants of that module.
3. `i` can never appear in a variable definition context: it is a constant not a variable.

The `save` attribute (in the current standard any module variable has this attribute; even `i` in the second example is saved) does not control modification.

Comment: Can you expand on what `save` actually does (in the context of a module variable)? It seems like you're saying nothing.

Comment: @Ross, indeed, `save` has no effect at all on a module variable.  Under F2008 onward all module variables are saved regardless of whether the save attribute is explicitly specified (with a `save` statement or `save` attribute specification in a declaration), or implicitly through the initialization (`integer :: i=1` (in)famously giving the save attribute implicitly in other contexts).  Before F2008 this is different.  (There may be questions here about that for more detail.)

Comment: Implicit SAVEing of module variables had become the usual practice in compilers before the f2008 standard was developed, so this standard simply ratifies the practice, and setting standard version options will make no difference.  In principle, before that, a module USEd in a procedure could have gone out of scope along with local variables.